# Custom Shipping Per Country per product

Tags: shipping, custom

I have this customer who sells large Antique items, they are tough to ship especially for international orders, he wants to calculate shipping only at the point when someone orders as it is almost custom price based on item and destination.

We are using Community edition 1.7 is the version.

Can we delay the order, say in some state and email him a shipping estimate, if the customer is ok with it, we confirm the order and ship, customer should be allowed to pay at this point.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Note: This is on hold, any ideas on what other detail can help add clarity would help me add the same, please write some comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common issue, but there are no easy solution.

What can you do is
1) allow them to place  orders with payment type "Money Order" so no actual payment involved.
2) Edit the order in admin (this cancels the original order) and set the required shipping cost
3) get payment offline.

Or send them a private link to a new product with right price+shipping cost combined.